# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'tensorflow' on Windows 10 x64, Anaconda with spyder 4.0.1 and python 3.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

**Solutions tried:**

pip install tensorflow

pip show tensorflow --ignore_installed

pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0

conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

conda install tensorflow

pip3 show tensorflow

pip show tensorflow
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
WARNING: Package(s) not found: tensorflow
Tried restarting kernel.
Tried restarting laptop

**Code trying to run:**
from keras.models import load_model

**Error:**
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/chinm/untitled1.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\chinm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\chinm\untitled1.py", line 14, in 
from keras.models import load_model

File "C:\Users\chinm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '

**ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`**

Comment: Are you trying all of this in separate Conda environments? Please share the contents of each one, we can't even attempt to reproduce this otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code, but it appears your key error is `Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2`, while you installed `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0`. 2.0 < 2.2. Have you tried installing tensorflow 2.2 or up, or upgrading your existing version?

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip recommends:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

with

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

to verify the installation.

Comment: **Ran:** pip install --upgrade tensorflow
**Ran:** pip show tensorflow
**Output:**
     Name: tensorflow
     Version: 2.3.0
     Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.

**Ran:** import tensorflow as tf
**Output:**
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.